# Representing complex/nested data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, dictionary

I am trying to send slightly complicated from my Rails app through JSON to a JS script to render the page in some interesting manner. Let us say the data in Rails is about people and their assets and looks like this:

```
[
  {:name => 'Bill Smith', :state => 'KS'} => [
    {:type => 'house', :valuation => 150000},
    {:type => 'car', :valuation => 10000}
  ], 
  {:name => 'Bubba Jack', :state => 'FL'} => [
    {:type => 'boat', :valuation => 12000}
  ]
]
```

On the JS side, I want to be able to access the individual fields, However, JS doesn't allow the keys of objects to be objects, so data.to_json converts all the person details into one string like this:

```
[{"{:name=>\"Bill Smith\", :state=>\"KS\"}":[{"type":"house","valuation":150000},{"type":"car","valuation":10000}],"{:name=>\"Bubba Jack\", :state=>\"FL\"}":[{"type":"boat","valuation":12000}]}]
```

I can't do stuff like

```
var people = Object.keys(data);
for(var i=0; i<people.length; i++) {
    var totAsset = 0;
    var person = people[i];
    for(var j=0;j<data[person].length; j++) {
        totAssset = totAsset + data[person][j].valuation
    }
    alert("got person named " +person.name+" having $"+totAsset);
}
```

What is the 'right' way to represent and use complex data on the JS side of an AJAX app?

**Update:** So both sgrif and Andrew's answers provide a solution to this particular problem. I've upvoted both of them, but I'll wait a few to see if there is a more general idea someone has to represent objects as keys or something with that functionality before accepting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to organize your records as such:

```
@people = [
    {:name => 'Bill Smith', :state => 'KS', :assets => [
        {:type => 'house', :valuation => 150000},
        {:type => 'car', :valuation => 10000}
    ]}, 
    {:name => 'Bubba Jack', :state => 'FL', :assets => [
        {:type => 'boat', :valuation => 12000}
    ]}
]
```

Then use "render :json => @people", which will give you.

```
{[ "name": 'Bill Smith', "state": 'KS', "assets": [
    {"type": 'house', "valuation": 150000},
    {"type": 'car', "valuation": 10000},
],
[ "name": 'Bubba Jack', "state": 'FL', "assets": [
    {"type": 'boat', "valuation": 12000}
]}
```

Then access the values as such.

```
'Bill Smith' = people[0]["name"]
'house'      = people[0]["assets"][0]["type"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[
  {name: "Bill Smith", state: "KS", possessions: [
    {type: "house", valuation: 1500000},
    {type: "car", valuation: 10000}
  ]},
  etc...
]
```